# Ayuda con un error de compilación

Tags: c#

La idea del código es solicitar un IPAddress, verificarlo(no estoy segura de como hacerlo) si es valido pedir usuario y contraseña (tiene tres intentos para ingresar usuario y contraseña)... Ayuda, por favor no me compila (Hasta ahora inicio en el campo)

el error que me aparece es : " El operador '<=' no se puede aplicar a operadores del tipo string"... Lo que sucede es que no estoy muy segura del tipo de dato para la IP y si el while con esta misma está correcta

```
namespace Escritorio_Remoto
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string User, Pass;
            int intentos = 0;
            string IP;
            Console.WriteLine("----Bienvenido al Escritorio Remoto----");
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la IP a la que desea conectarse (utilizando comas", "): ");
            IP = Console.ReadLine ();
            IP = "0,0,0,0";
            while (IP<="255,255,255,255")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("La IP ingresada es correcta.");
                Console.WriteLine("Ingrese Usuario: ");
                User = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Ingrese La Contraseña: ");
                Pass = Console.ReadLine(); Console.Clear();
                User = "1234";
                Pass="0000";
                intentos += 1;
                if ((Pass == "0000")&&(User == "1234"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Conexión Satisfactoria, Bienveni@ " + User);
                }
                else if (intentos>3)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Ha alcanzado el número máximo de intentos.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Usuario y Contraseña Incorrectas.");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Conexión Fallida.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Con verificarlo te refieres a probar la conexion o si tiene un formato adecuado ? (creo que formato por esto que pones `IP<="255,255,255,255"`) . Y dices que no te compila, qué errores te da? Es por lo de `IP <=` imagino .Un saludo

Comment: Si entiendo bien, la idea no es *perfeccionar* el código como dice el título, y lo que sería demasiado amplio o un asunto de opinión. Mas bien, quieres corregir el error de compilación. Pero te falta compartir el error que recibes y en cuales líneas las recibes.

Comment: Si, lo que imaginaba. El tipo lo tienes bien, es de tipo `String`. Lo que tienes que hacer es verificar el formato adecuado, y puedes usar  [tag:regex] para eso

Comment: Es tu tarea de la facu verdad?

Comment: Marcela, las preguntas de Tareas no suelen ser bien recibidas. para que si sea una buena pregunta, has de intentar dos cosas. 1- Comprobar el fomrato de IP (te recomiendo [tag:regex]).2- Comprobar el usuario y contraseña 3 veces. Lo que tienes no sirve. Primero **Intentalo, y si no te sale o tienes errores, pregunta.** Tal y como lo tienes y lo que pides es muy amplio. Un saludo

Comment: El operador `while` no tiene razón de estar ahí, lo puedes evaluar solo con `if`. Revisa: [while (Referencia de C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/2aeyhxcd.aspx). Más bien si quieres evaluar la cantidad de intentos puedes hacerlo con [do (Referencia de C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/370s1zax.aspx).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

El problema obvio es que no tienes derecho a comparar cadenas usando el operador `<=` como si se trata de números.

Si tuvieras que efectuar esa clase de comparación con cadenas, tendrías que usar [`String.CompareTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/35f0x18w(v=vs.110).aspx). Pero en tu caso, no es eso lo que debes hacer.

Mas bien, siendo que tu intención es simplemente verificar si el IP es correcto, te sugiero de usar [`IPAddress.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) que para eso fue diseñado.  Y de ser el caso, no uses comas en el IP address, sino puntos, ya que las comas no son válidas en un IP Address.

Aparte de eso, la lógica del bucle mismo no se ve claro. Te tocará revisar la lógica, si es que quieres permitiar varios intentos o no para ingresar un IP address válido.

Comment: y el nombre de las variables en minusculas xD